# how to cancel drop event in jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju_Bollera/5vuzagkw/) I want only one item to be dragged from each group(Fruits,Celebrity,Mobile Phones) to any one of the step. I tried by not allowing using return false, but return false doesn't seemed to work. Please help me not to drag and drop more than one element from each group to any of the rules.

I can add atmost add only 3 items to any of the group.

Here is my sample code which i wrote for not drop the element if the group is already present.

```
$("#Rule1List,#Rule2List,#Rule3List").on("drop",function  (element,ui) {

    $("#Rule1List>li,#Rule2List>li,#Rule3List>li").each(function  (index) {
      if($(this).eq(index).hasClass($(ui.draggable).attr('class')))
      {
        console.log($(ui));
        return false;
      }
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i am not gonna give you the code to solve this but a suggest might be beneficial for you

On drag of any item from any group just take size of items in that particular group i.e. length of item. for example in phone group you have 4 items. so on drag item store this size in a variable. on drop remove that particular item from item group. and check if current length of item group is less than previously stored size than remove draggable class and event from that particular itemgroup

Comment: try this one in mean while i am solving your question in fiddle

Comment: I did it and its working fine... i have updated the fiddle..  http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju_Bollera/5vuzagkw/2/

Comment: Great. than please accept this answer and give me positive handsup

Comment: I dont understand y is the dragged element coming at the back of the rule block when i drag the element ? any suggestion will be helpful,,

Comment: actually you have to through all properties of drag and drop to understand how to remove from input groups and all. so read this doc carefully in jquery for drag and drop and their all events.